# Adding index to column list python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

So I do work on files with over 100 columns using pandas. Each time I need to choose only those I need. So instead of using **DataFrame.loc** I was thinking about using **DataFrame.iloc** with specifying only column no.

So I am trying to loop over a list of column names and add an integer that could help me to add the index to each column.

So I have a DataFrame called **Data** and columns names

**['VIN','MODEL','ENGINE']**

I would like to return a list of:

**['VIN 1','MODEL 2','ENGINE 3']**

I tried with the code below and it does basically what I need but the result is not quite alright since it's printing every column name the same number of times as the len(Data.columns)

```
col_desc = Data.columns

col_list = list(col_desc)

range(len(col_list))

for i in range(len(col_list)):
    for col in col_desc:
        print(col_desc[i] + ' ' + str(i))
```

Could you suggest any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
# dummy setup
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['VIN','MODEL','ENGINE'])

# change columns
df.columns = [f'{col} {i}' for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1)]

print(df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
Index(['VIN 1', 'MODEL 2', 'ENGINE 3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: You probably mean `f'{col} {i + 1}'`.

Comment: @Jarvis Updated the answer, enumerate receives a parameter for starting

Comment: Is dataframes.columns of List type?

Comment: @ConSod No, is an index. See the output. But you can assign a list to columns pandas will take care of converting it

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with `map` and `enumerate`:

```
col_list = list(map(lambda x: f"{x[1]} {x[0]}", enumerate(Data.columns, 1)))
```